# Incorrect limits when using geom_smooth with geom_rug

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set that I fit a trend line to using `geom_smooth`, as shown in the first figure below. That's great, but I'd like to add `geom_rug` to it. By default, it is plotted on both the left and bottom, as shown in the second figure. Nevertheless, I'd like it just on the bottom axis, so use the `sides = "b"` parameter in the third figure below.

**The problem**: the y limits in the third figure are automatically set assuming that `geom_rug` also appears in the vertical aspect. I would like the y limits to be the same as in the first figure. (I'd argue that they *should* be the same as in the first figure. Why all that extra space when nothing is being plotted in it?!) Of course, I can manually set the y limits, but is there a straightforward way to prevent `geom_rug` from resetting the y limits unnecessarily?

---

#### MCVE

```r
# Set RNG seed
set.seed(42)

# Create dummy data set
df <- data.frame(x = runif(1000, 0, 10))
df$y <- df$x + rnorm(nrow(df), 0, 5)

# Load library
library(ggplot2)

# Plot trend line
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_smooth()
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'gam' and formula 'y ~ s(x, bs = "cs")'
```

[image]

```r
# Plot trends line with rug on left and bottom
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_smooth() + geom_rug()
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'gam' and formula 'y ~ s(x, bs = "cs")'
```

[image]

```r
# Plot trends line with rug on bottom
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_smooth() + geom_rug(sides = "b")
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'gam' and formula 'y ~ s(x, bs = "cs")'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as I ask, I figured it out. Here, I simply set `y` to `NULL` and no resizing occurs.

```r
# Set RNG seed
set.seed(42)

# Create dummy data set
df <- data.frame(x = runif(1000, 0, 10))
df$y <- df$x + rnorm(nrow(df), 0, 5)

# Load library
library(ggplot2)

# Plot trends line with rug on left and bottom
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_smooth() + geom_rug(sides = "b", aes(y = NULL))
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'gam' and formula 'y ~ s(x, bs = "cs")'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Yes, the issue seems to come from setting a y value to `geom_rug()` which is expecting only an `x` parameter. An alternative would be to leave the `aes()` out of the first `ggplot()` call: `ggplot(df) + geom_smooth(aes(x,y)) + geom_rug(sides = 'b', aes(x))`

Comment: @Chris Yes, that's a good alternative. Actually, in my answer, setting `y` to `NULL` rather than a value probably makes more sense. I'll update it.